# Is it possible to get report results in a flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, reporting

I want to run a report, and use some of the output in a flow.

1. How can I trigger a report within a flow?
2. How can I get the report output inside the flow?

Comment: One of the approaches could be to use APEX in order to get report data (as shown in here for example - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_analytics_report_data.htm ) and wrap it up in invocable method to be called from flow